# Is it possible to change text in hover tool-tip for Plotlyjs bubble chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I have a Plotlyjs bubble chart in my website. On hover the tooltip shows x,y and text. I want a customized text in the tool-tip, is this functionality available?

Example: http://codepen.io/sushilaitian/pen/NbGZzq

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('my-graph');
        Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv', function(err, rows){
        var YEAR = 2007;
        var continents = ['Asia', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Oceania', 'Americas'];
        var POP_TO_PX_SIZE = 2e5;
        function unpack(rows, key) {
          return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
        }

        var data = continents.map(function(continent) {
          var rowsFiltered = rows.filter(function(row) {
              return (row.continent === continent) && (+row.year === YEAR);
          });
          return {
              mode: 'markers',
              name: continent,
              x: unpack(rowsFiltered, 'lifeExp'),
              y: unpack(rowsFiltered, 'gdpPercap'),
              text: unpack(rowsFiltered, 'country'),
              marker: {
                  sizemode: 'area',
                  size: unpack(rowsFiltered, 'pop'),
                  sizeref: POP_TO_PX_SIZE
              }
          };
        });
        var layout = {
          xaxis: {title: 'Life Expectancy'},
          yaxis: {title: 'GDP per Capita', type: 'log'},
          margin: {t: 20},
          hovermode: 'closest'
        };
        Plotly.plot('my-graph', data, layout, {showLink: false});
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
                var pts = '';
                for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
                    pts = 'x = '+data.points[i].x +'\ny = '+
                        data.points[i].y.toPrecision(4) + '\n\n';
                }
                alert('Closest point clicked:\n\n'+pts);
            });         
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: What kind of customized text do you need? You can set the text via the text attribute, https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-text

Answer (score 0):

Plotly has [`hoverinfo`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#box-hoverinfo) setting for some basic level of control over the hover text:

> Any combination of `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"`, `"text"`, `"name"` joined with a `"+"` OR `"all"` or `"none"` or `"skip"`.
>
> examples: `"x"`, `"y"`, `"x+y"`, `"x+y+z"`, `"all"`
>
> default: `"all"`
>
> Determines which trace information appear on hover. If `none` or `skip` are set, no information is displayed upon hovering. But, if `none` is set, click and hover events are still fired.

However for more complex examples you need to use the `text` part of the data. This can be set to a custom value and then set `hoverinfo: "text"`.

For example see this [heatmap Codepen](http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/WxLGoo)